# The items of my enum type are not translated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following view model:

```
public class BudgetTypeSiteRowListViewModel
{
    public virtual int BudgetTypeSiteID { get; set; }
    public virtual string SiteName { get; set; }
    public virtual BudgetTypeEnumViewModel SiteType { get; set; }        
}
```

With the following enum:

```
public enum BudgetTypeEnumViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "BudgetTypeDaily", ResourceType = typeof (UserResource))] Daily = 1,
    [Display(Name = "BudgetTypeRevision", ResourceType = typeof (UserResource))] Revision = 2
}
```

And the following view for listing my items:

```
@model IEnumerable<BudgetTypeSiteRowListViewModel>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.SiteName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.SiteType)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**The problem** is that my items listed are not in the right culture. I have 'Daily' or 'Revision' where I should have 'Journalier' or 'Dagelijkse' or 'Révision' or 'Revisie'.

How can I have my SiteType in the right culture (provided from my enum)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write an extension method that use reflection to get the enume type of your property

```
public static string DisplayAttribute<TEnum>(this TEnum enumValue) where TEnum : struct
{
  //You can't use a type constraints on the special class Enum. So I use this workaround
  if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
    throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be of type System.Enum");

  Type type = typeof(TEnum);
  MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumValue.ToString());
  if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
  {
    object[] attrs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
    if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
      return ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
  }
  return enumValue.ToString();
}
```

From the view you will get th value like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.SiteType.DisplayAttribute())
```

I hope it helps